# Simple Login Form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, controls

I have to create a simple ASP login page. We're not using Windows authentication or anything like that. The project is a conversion from a legacy VB6 program. Login accounts and passwords are stored in a SQL table, not the way to do it, but it is what it is. I can call the old login functions and redirect the window based on the return values.

Is there a decent-looking login form out there I could use? I tried the login control in the toolbox, but that thing seems to be married to Windows authentication.

I really just need an empty control that looks good. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Jason

Comment: You can use the login control from the toolbox and use forms authentication to use your own logic for authorizing users.

Comment: Google for "Login Templates".. http://www.artfans.info/login-page-template-tag-style/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google for "Login Templates".. artfans.info/login-page-template-tag-style – Nikhil Bhandari